What wire size for underground wire?
I need to run a direct burial wire from my pole to my shop. It is 150ft run length. Just running led lights, fans, air compressors what size service wire do I need?

You need to know how much power will be used and the breaker size in amps.  Air compressors/etc will be the main/heavy users, then fans if big.  Bigger wire size than needed right now is good for future plan changes.  It sucks to dig the second time.

Your question doesn't provide enough context for anyone to answer. What size panel will you install? What size is the feeder breaker (if present)? Please see [ask], then revise to add more detail. Also note that many similar questions exist on this site. Give the search a go.

Is this the only building on the meter or is there another building? What kind of panel will it be feeding from? What kind of panel will it be feeding to? What is the utility service size? If there is another building then we need a Load Calculation of the existing building.

For that distance, Large aluminum wire/cable will probably be much cheaper than copper, even if much larger than needed for the breaker.  Something like 2-2-2-4 Al(good for 90 amps) might be cheaper than 10 or 8 gauge copper(good for 30 or 40 amps).  Aluminum is good big, not so good small.

Air compressir for an air brush, or somehting more demanding?  LED grow lights or something smaller? are you building a wind tunnel, or are the fans smalll?

Your question is a bit vague, but unless you are installing some huge undisclosed load the narrow answer to question is probably 2-2-2-4 Al MHF.
Bare minimum load is going to be 30A, requiring 10/3, but 150' is right in the range when voltage drop becomes an issue, so one size larger is needed.
Copper 8/3 UF is about $2.25/ft, and 2-2-2-4 Al MHF is under $2.00 and is legal for 90A and good with voltage drop for 80A easily.
You still need to do a "load calc" do determine the power available and the power needed, which will determine the up to 90 amp breaker you will be allowed  to use to protect the feeder, but barring the surprise welders 2-2-2-4 is likely your end result.
And if you are worried about using aluminum the 8000 series aluminum alloy they produce now safe and is so different from the 1300 series used back in the 70's that they really should give the 8000 series a new name.

I actually just did this to feed 175 feet to my barn, but local  inspector didn't require load calc since I was replacing clearance challenged overhead #4 with burial #2.
